# How to save Camunda decision rules in database

Tags: bpmn, camunda, dmn

We are facing an issue with Camunda orchestrator restarts.

We lose all decision rules of DMNs after deploying new versions of processes.

Could you please suggest if possible an out of the box solution to save rules and reload them after restart, if not possible an explanation of how to do it is OK also ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have one version of the dmn in your src/main/resources, so it's auto deployed on start ... and then deploy updated versions "on the fly" via REST.
You have to update the table in resources as well or disable auto-deployment to not overwrite your ad-hoc changes again.

Comment: thanks Jan, You mean, that we add rules also in src/main/resources? in this case we will need to restart the application for every change. could you please suggest another way, ? maybe saving the config in a database, is there an "out of box" way to do it ? if you can point an article that will be nice.
thanks

Comment: The problem is your mixed mode. If you have dmns in your resources, and auto-deployment active, they will be deployed and overwrite your changes. So either you ensure that the dmns in resources are the latest versions ... or you remove them from resources completely and rely solely on runtime changes.

Answer (score 1):

Please also see: [Camunda load BPMN XML from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692725/camunda-load-bpmn-xml-from-database/63698593#63698593)

The same explanation applies to any kind of model (BPMN,DMN,CMMN)