# Camunda load BPMN XML from database

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda

Is it possible to load BPMN XML from a database in Camunda rather than having the XML in files in with the web app?

We want to be able to dynamically add new workflows rather than deploy a new WAR with the definitions the idea is add to the database and notify the webapp there are new definitions.

How this makes sense!

Thanks,
Scott.

Answer (score 4):

Camunda stores the model/deployment versions in the DB. Bundling the file in the deployment is just one way of (auto) deploying a process model.

If auto deployment is enabled and the model has changes then the process model will be deployed as a new version to the database during startup.

> "isScanForProcessDefinitions: if this property is set to true, the
> classpath of the process application is automatically scanned for
> deployable resources. Deployable resources must end in .bpmn20.xml,
> .bpmn, .cmmn11.xml, .cmmn, .dmn11.xml or .dmn."
> https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-applications/the-processes-xml-deployment-descriptor/

[image: Re/deployment of model files]

At any (run)time you can deploy a new model version via [REST](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/deployment/) or Java API ([RepositoryService](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.14/)).
For instance you can use the Camunda modeler to deploy a new version:
https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/quick-start/deploy/
or for instance curl or postman.

Also see:

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/webapps/cockpit/deployment-view/
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-engine/process-versioning/